# Rspec, have_xpath vs have_css filtering searching in the DOM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xpath, rspec, magicsuggest

I am using the truly nice [MagicSuggest](http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/index.html) library.

Basic use example: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ttttoni/5Q6YA/)

As one can see, once you initialize magic suggest in your selected `input`, it appends new `div`'s with pre-fixed `class`es .

In order to display the possible select options, one needs to click on the dropdown icon, which Magic Suggest indicates giving it `class="ms-trigger"`.
The dropdown showed has `class="ms-res-ctn"`, where each select option has `class="ms-res-item"`.

I am testing that whenever I click on a `class="ms-res-item"` this is added to the input and then updates my model via ajax(although this is another topic).

What I can't understand is:

```rb
#Somewhere in my test
expect(page).to have_css('div.ms-res-item') #<-- This WORKS

expect(page).to have_xpath('.//div[@class="ms-res-item"]') #<- This DOESNT
```

I know for sure the `'div > .ms-res-item'` is there, I just don't know why `have_xpath` or `find(:xpath,...)` cannot find it, whereas `have_css` can.

**Update:**These are the options I see afer inspecting the DOM

```
<div class="ms-res-item ms-res-item-active" data-json={"id":"paris","name":"paris"}>
<div class="ms-res-item" data-json={"id":"newyork","name":"newyork"}>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS class names added to the DOM elements are dynamic and so you sometimes end up with things like this:

```
<div class="ms-res-item " data-json="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;New York&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;New York&quot;}">New York</div>
```

Now when you do this:

```
expect(page).to have_xpath('.//div[@class="ms-res-item"]')
```

It looks for the exact value `"ms-res-item"` on the `class` attribute. As you can see this is not true as the value is just parsed as a string and `"ms-res-item "` !=  `"ms-res-item"`

So 2 options:

1/ it's an open source project. You can submit a request to get the class defs cleaned up (or better yet do it yourself and then ask for a merge request).

2/ you can change your code to `expect(page).to have_xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"ms-res-item")]')`

Comment: Hey Nicolas, very helpful reply! I did not spot that whitespace at all. I will surely try to clean it up myself and submit a merge request when I have a bit of time. Thanks for this nice library! :)

Comment: karlipoppins: I edited my question appending the literal code that magic-suggest adds. Apparently one of the options has a whitespace, whereas the other option doesn't, shouldn't it match the second one then? `have_xpath` does deal with dynamically appended content to the DOM, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need selenium to test JS features in Rspec.
1)  So install the gem  'selenium-webdriver', '~> 2.42.0'.  Bundle.
2) If you have validations on your tests you will also need to install the gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.3.0'.
if you need database_cleaner you will need to  set config.use_transactional_fixtures = false in spec helper and have a file that looks like this:  https://gist.github.com/EvanTedesco/e2232e09cd16bb2faab4   in you spec support file.

3) after the it block (or scenario whichever you use) you need js: true   ex:

```
it "does supercool stuff", js:true do.  
end
```

4) profit.

Comment: hey, thanks! But I am already using `database_cleaner`, and I've got to use `poltergeist` driver instead of selenium, for other reasons. Also the `js: :true`is enabled :)